# Texworks cursor vanish on compile completion

Tags: texworks

This is a very stupid question. I use texworks all the time, and it does this thing, where every time it finishes compiling a document, the cursor in the source file vanishes, even if I'm in the middle

Comment: And sorry if this is a stupid reply. Does it disappear and not come back? It "disappears" for me to, but that is just because the focus switches to the PDF-viewer, if I Alt+Tab back to the editor, the cursor reappears.

Comment: That does work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor is only visible when the editor window is active/in focus. Whenever a compilation finishes, focus switches to the PDF viewer, which is a separate window. Hence the cursor disappears.  If you switch back to the editor window, e.g. with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or by clicking the title bar, the cursor will reappear.